# Pointer troubles

Tags: c, pointers

I have an issue with the following code.

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {

#define MAXCHARACTERS 10
#define MAXNUMBERS 2

char buffer[MAXCHARACTERS];

numberOfStructs = 0;

allocSize = 10;
array = malloc(allocSize * sizeof(StructItem));
dataLink *link;

do
{
    Album *tempStruct;

    fgets(&(*tempStruct->firstField),MAXCHARACTERS, stdin);
    fgets(&(*tempStruct->secondField), MAXCHARACTERS, stdin);
    fgets(buffer, MAXNUMBERS, stdin);
    sscanf(buffer, "%d", &(tempStruct->thirdField) == 1); // line 26

    link = List(&tempStruct);

    array[numberOfStructs] = (*tempStructs);
    numberOfStructs += 1;

    array = reAllocArray(&array, &allocSize, numberOfstructs);
}
while(link->newStruct != NULL);

printList(&array, numberOfStructs);
freeArray(&array, numberOfStructs);
}
```

I get warnings as follows

> /main.c:26: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
>   warning: passing argument 1 of 'List' from incompatible pointer type

I get a few of the "passing argument 1" error messages.

What am I doing wrong with these pointers?

Thanks

Comment: What is the type of `Album`?  Or rather, how have you defined that type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Album *tempStruct;
fgets(&(*tempStruct->firstField),MAXCHARACTERS, stdin);
```

tempStruct is just a pointer and you should not store anything on this pointer offset

```
&(*tempStruct->firstField) // or just tempStruct->firstField since &* is just cancellation
```

I am not sure how this code works but from my knowledge i can see that each line using tempStruct is access violation without exception at

```
link = List(&tempStruct);
```

and

```
&(tempStruct->thirdField) == 1
```

Will be most likley FALSE in all cases since it is just pointer which can be 1 just by accident.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you are misusing `sscanf`, the third parameter you are passing to it is the logical result from a comparison between an address and the number 1. What are you trying to accomplish there?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing multiple type definitions.

For example, `numberOfStructs = 0;` should be `int numberOfStructs = 0;` The same applies to `allocSize`, `array`, and `datalink`.

If you only posted snippets of your code and your original code does *not* have those problems, then please let us know which line of code causing the error. The line numbers are likely incorrect.

Comment: I have them in a header file.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you just copied code that also does test the return of `scanf` against `1`? Then you have gotten your `()` wrong. And effectively you should put that into an `if` clause and test for success.